# Не работает LocalDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Не могу корректно установить EntityFramework и LocalDB. Ошибка на ошибке, пробовал много методов, ничего не помогло.

1. При добавлении EntityFramework в решение не создается App/Web.config, что не дает возможности установить connectionString.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Установил SQL Server Express 2019. (Переустанавливал несколько раз, также ставил через Visual Studio Installer). При попытке подключиться/запустить сервер выдает ошибку:

[image: start of LocalDB instance “mssqllocaldb” failed because of the following error: jo Bpema aanycka axzennnapa LocalDB npowsouna own6xa: owm6Ka sanycKa npouecca SQL Server.]

> start of LocalDB instance “mssqllocaldb” failed because of the
> following error: Во время запуска экземпляра LocalDB произошла ошибка:
> ошибка запуска процесса SQL Server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Cannot connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
> Во время запуска экземпляра LocalDB произошла ошибка: ошибка запуска
> процесса SQL Server. ) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1983577846)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Все операции выполнялись через администратора)
Опять же, переустановка не решает проблемы, перед переустановкой полностью очищал предыдущую версию и удалял временные файлы.

Не имею понятия, как решить проблему.

(Ради интереса пытался установить полностью ядро СУБД SQL Server, установка вообще не завершилась из-за ошибки)

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Гляньте в Add or Remove Programs, нет ли там остатков другой версии Sql Server. Если есть - поудаляйте всё.